# 9 patch image proper aligning and resizing

Tags: android, image, nine-patch

Lets say I have the following image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [giorgos.nl](http://www.giorgos.nl/test/Default.png))</sub>

how should I setup it up in the online 9 patch tool in order the banner on the top to remain the same on all android devices (no stretches), centered horizontally and aligned to the top?